# Why is setter of dataprovider not called after filtering an arraycollection using filter function

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

I am using this:

```
private var _hrInfoView:ArrayCollection;
 [Bindable]
 public function get HRInfoView():ArrayCollection
  {
   return _hrInfoView;
   }
  public function set HRInfoView(value:ArrayCollection):void
  {
   _hrInfoView = value;
  }

 private function onFilterByContent(event:ContextMenuEvent):void
 {              
    HRInfoView.filterFunction = processFilter;  
    HRInfoView.refresh();
  //Break point here shows HRInfoView as different what is in line above. Why is setter not called?
}
```

When I put breakpoint on setter of HRInfoView, it never gets hit (when I can clearly see in the watch expression that HRInfoView has changed before and after filtering)! Why?
Thanks.

Comment: Is there no one to answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** After reading the question again, I think I see your problem.

When you apply a filter function to an ArrayCollection, you're not actually affecting the ArrayCollection. Flex creates a copy of the ArrayCollection and puts it in a "wrapper" and only includes the records that match your filter. This is why your setter is never called.

If you call ArrayCollection.length on the filtered collection it will show the number of the filtered records instead of the total number of records you started with. If you remove the filter function and call the refresh() method, that "wrapper" collection is removed.

You don't need to do anything special to get that "wrapper" copy of the ArrayCollection. Flex automatically returns the filtered/wrapper copy of the collection whenever you use the original ArrayCollection.

[This link](http://www.albertx.mx/blog/filter-an-arraycollection-and-dont-lose-the-original-data/) has some additional info.

Comment: Tried that. Still the same problem.

Comment: More important question should be, what does filter function actually do? It does not probably change the dataprovider at all! Could you provide me some insight into that? Thanks.

Comment: @user Can you post the code where you're binding the ArrayCollection to your DataGrid?

Comment: @user The filterFunction is used to filter an Array Collection to only show the items that match certain criteria. Once you apply a filter function to your ArrayCollection and call the refresh() method, it will remove all of the rows that do not match your filter. Check out http://www.brandonellis.org/?p=69 for a quick example.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I knew that much already... What I needed to know was how filterfunction actually works... when you say it eliminates, how does it do it? Because i can see that setter is not called even after filtering and I need to know the reason of this behaviour...thanks again... I am going to post the full code soon...

Comment: @user I believe what it does is create a copy of the ArrayCollection with only the records that match the filter function included. It doesn't affect your original ArrayCollection. Your setter will never get called in this instance because it's not actually affecting the original ArrayCollection.

Comment: Exactly. Thats what I suspected too. Then how do I retrieve that copy of new ArrayCollection? Thanks...

Comment: @user I updated my answer to hopefully explain things a bit better. Let me know if you still have any questions.

Comment: Jason, I am trying to add some cumulative search on the filtered array collection only... thats why I need to have the copy of filtered array collection... could I get it easily or the manual iteration though the array collection is my only choice? Thanks.

Comment: @user What do you mean by "I am trying to add some cumulative search on the filtered array collection only"? Are you trying to add records to just the filtered array collection and not the original collection?

Comment: Jason, I am using this filter function on right click of datagrid (filter by content)... apart from that I have a custom search component in my page. I wanted that search component to act on the filtered data only (since the dataprovider of both are the same)... Nonehtless, I created an another copy using ObjectUtil.copy() to save filtered arraycollection (looping it on the new shortened length)... its working... I was just hoping to get the filtered ArrayCollection without having to loop... but this discussion cleared some doubts... thanks for the time and help... appreciate it...

Comment: @user No worries. I'm glad you got it working. If my answer helped, I'd appreciate an upvote on my answer. If it helped solve your problem, you can mark it as the accepted answer as well. :)

Answer (score 1):

[go here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ArrayCollection.html) and read up on source

[EDIT]

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

        [Bindable]
        public var myAC:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([{label:"One"}, {label:"Two"}, {label:"Three"}, {label:"Four"}]);

        [Bindable]
        public var myAC2:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

        public function removeFilter(e:Event):void{
            trace(this.myAC.source.length )
            this.myAC.filterFunction = null;
            this.myAC.refresh()
            trace(this.myAC.source.length )
        }
        public function addFilter(e:Event):void{
            trace(this.myAC.source.length )
            this.myAC.filterFunction = filterFunc;
            this.myAC.refresh()
            trace(this.myAC.source.length )
        }
        public function filterFunc( item:Object ):Boolean{
            if( item.label == "One" )
                return true;

            if( item.label == "Two" )
                return true;

            return false;
        }
        public function copyData(e:Event):void{
            myAC2 =   new ArrayCollection( myAC.toArray() );  
            myAC2.refresh()
        }
    ]]> 
</mx:Script>
<mx:Label text="original data with filter option"  y="0"/>
<mx:DataGrid y="26" id="nameGrid" dataProvider="{myAC}" width="200" height="200"/>
<mx:Button id="button2" label="Add Filter" click="addFilter(event)" x="0" y="234"/>
<mx:Button id="button3" y="264" label="Remove Filter" click="removeFilter(event)"/>


<mx:Button id="button4" x="289" y="234" label="copy filtered data" click="copyData(event)"/>
<mx:Label text="Copied filtered data"  x="300" y="0"/>
<mx:DataGrid  y="26" x="287" id="nameGrid2" dataProvider="{myAC2}" width="200" height="200"/>
```

Comment: that link is good for application level only... I needed to know how filterfunction actually works... when you say it eliminates, how does it do it? Because i can see that setter is not called even after filtering and I need to know the reason of this behaviour...

Comment: filter functions don't call or set data they work by examining each element in the arraycollection and returning true or false. I will post a sample function shortly

Comment: Ok I added a sample for you create a new project and try this out

Comment: I am sorry Tom, but I guess you have completely misinterpreted my question.  I am not asking this. I know how to use it very well. And I know the functionality as well. If you would follow the question again and the above comments between me and Jason, you will know what is the issue here. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Whats not to understand I answered everything you asked in my sample. I also added a filter remove function. The original data never goes away its just filtered. Just remove the filter function and you have the data.

Comment: And again back to my first statement the source property of the Array collection is NOT bindable. If you want the original data with no filters applied _hrInfoView.source will give it to you.

Comment: And just to make sure you have the question in your title answered. "Why is setter of dataprovider not called after filtering an arraycollection using filter function" Setters do NOT get called during the filter process or the refresh process. You have a gross misunderstanding of what the setters are doing. A setter AKA assignor is used to set the value of a class property. Do not confuse a custom class setter with the data setters of the ArrayCollection class.

Comment: Setters and Getters are mere functions (to ease developers of the burden to create custom functions to set private members, the way it used to happen in good old C++ days). The way you want to use it, depends on you. Custom or Extended. In this case the component where I am using the array collection is custom and I have only posed a small snippet of the code.  The issue is, as Jason and I have discussed is : filter function is not modifying the original array collection (and setter is not getting called). It is merely hiding the filtered elements from the source array of array collection.

Comment: user I updated my edit to show you how to get the filtered data please actually try it this time.

Comment: You also might want to read up on setters and getters you have a misunderstanding on how they work. ArrayCollection will not call the setter of the class that instantiated it

Comment: Yes thats one of the ways... But I did it just by shortening the original dataprovider by new length... thanks for the time... giving this one an upvote too :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's not calling the setter because you're not setting that property. What you're doing is calling the getter so that you can get the property off of it to set that.
Both `HRInfoView.filterFunction` and `HRInfoView.refresh()` are calling the getter to get `_hrInfoView`, then calling functions or properties from that.